# How to use Python API to upload and configure SSL certificate for an app service

Tags: python, azure, ssl, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to using the [Azure Python SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) to drive some server configuration management, but I'm having difficulty working out how I'm supposed to use the API to upload and configure SSL certificates.

I can successfully interrogate my Azure account to discovering the App Services that are available with the `WebSiteManagementClient`, and I can interrogate and manipulate DNS configurations using the `DnsManagementClient`.

I am also able to manually add an SSL certificate to an Azure App Service using [the instructions on the Azure website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate).

However, it isn't at all clear to me what API endpoints I should be using to install a custom SSL certificate.

If I've got a `WebSiteManagementClient` named `client`, then I can see that:

- `client.certificates.get_certificate()` allows me to get a specific certificate by name - but `client.certificates` doesn't appear to have an API to list all available certificates.
- `client.certificates.create_or_update_certificate()` allows me to presumably idempotently create/update a certificate - but it requires a `CertificateEnvelope` argument, and I can't see where that object should be created.
- Assuming I manually upload a certificate, I can't work out what API endpoint I would use to install that certificate on a site. There are calls to `get_site_host_name_bindings` and `delete_site_host_name_binding`, but no obvious API to *create* the binding; there are dozens of calls to `configure_...` and `create_or_update_...`, but neither the naming of the API endpoints nor the API documentation is in any way illuminating as to which calls should be used.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What Python API calls do I need to make to upload a certificate obtained from a third party, and install that certificate on an AppService under a specific domain?

## Addendum

Here's some sample code, based on suggestions from @peter-pan-msft:

```
creds = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id=UUID('<client>'),
    secret='<secret>',
    tenant=UUID('<tenant>'),
    resource='https://vault.azure.net'
)
kv = KeyVaultClient(
    credentials=creds
)
KEY_VAULT_URI = 'https://<vault>.vault.azure.net/'

with open('example.pfx', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

# Try to get the certificates
for cert in kv.get_certificates(KEY_VAULT_URI):
    print(cert)

# or...
kv.import_certificate(KEY_VAULT_URI, 'cert name', data, 'password')
```

This code raises:

```
KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
```

The values for the credentials have worked for other operations, including getting and creating keys in the key store. If I modify the credentials to be known bad values, I get:

```
KeyVaultErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [App Service walkthrough for importing certificates from Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#import-a-certificate-from-key-vault), it'll tell you that your app needs read permissions to access certificates from the vault. But to initially import your certificate to Key Vault as you're doing, you'll need to grant your service principal certificate import permissions as well. Trying to import a certificate without import permissions will yield a "Forbidden" error like the one you're seeing.

There are also new packages for working with Key Vault in Python that replace `azure-keyvault`:

- [azure-keyvault-certificates](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-certificates/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-certificates/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-keys](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-keys/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-keys/migration_guide.md)
- [azure-keyvault-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/azure-keyvault-secrets/) [(Migration guide)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets/migration_guide.md)

[azure-identity](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/) is the package that should be used with these for authentication.

Here's an example of importing a certificate using `azure-keyvault-certificates`:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.certificates import CertificateClient

KEY_VAULT_URI = 'https://<vault>.vault.azure.net/'

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = CertificateClient(KEY_VAULT_URI, credential)

with open('example.pfx', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

client.import_certificate("cert-name", data.encode(), password="password")
```

You can provide the same credentials that you used for `ServicePrincipalCredentials` by setting environment variables corresponding to the `client_id`, `secret`, and `tenant`:

```
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID="<client>"
export AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET="<secret>"
export AZURE_TENANT_ID="<tenant>"
```

(I work on the Azure SDK in Python)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, based on my understanding, I think you want to upload a certificate and use it on Azure App Service.

Per my experience for Azure Python SDK, there seems not to be any Python API for directly uploading a certificate to Azure App Service. However, there is a workaround way for doing it via import a certificate into Azure Key Vault and use it from Azure App Service. And for more details, please see the docuemtn list below.

1. The [`Import Certificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/importcertificate) REST API of `Key Valut`. And the related Azure Python API is the method `import_certificate` from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/61d49db3e3cc3d4821e823ce811f82b44a734b2a/azure-keyvault/azure/keyvault/key_vault_client.py#L173), you can refer to the [reference](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_azure-keyvault.html) for key Vault to know how to use it.
2. There are two documents about using Key Vault certificate from Azue WebApp: [Use Azure Key Vault from a Web Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application) & [Deploying Azure Web App Certificate through Key Vault](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/24/deploying-azure-web-app-certificate-through-key-vault/). The [`Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates#Certificates_CreateOrUpdate) REST API of Certificates on Azure App Service is used for deploying, and the related Python API is [`create_or_update`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/00678eb1cff3053077374dd527b6f564fd0fbb34/azure-mgmt-web/azure/mgmt/web/operations/certificates_operations.py#L236), for which usage, please refer to [here](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resourcemanagementapps.html).

Hope it helps.

---

As Azure Python SDK reference of KeyVault for [`Access Policy`](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_azure-keyvault.html#access-policies) said, as below.

> **Access policies**
>
> Some operations require the correct access policies for your credentials.
>
> If you get an “Unauthorized” error, please add the correct access policies to this credentials using the Azure Portal, the Azure CLI or the Key Vault Management SDK itself

Here is the steps for set access policies for certificates operations via [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/xplat-cli-install).

1. Get Azure AD service principals for your application, command `azure ad sp show --search <your-application-display-name>`, then copy the `Service Principal Names`(spn) like `xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx`.
2. Set policy for certificate operations, command `azure keyvault set-policy brucechen --spn <your-applicaiton-spn> --perms-to-certificates <perms-to-certificates, such as [\"all\"]>`. Explaination for The `<perms-to-certificates>` as below.

> JSON-encoded array of strings representing certificate operations; each string can be one of [all, get, list, delete, create, import, update, managecontacts, getissuers, listissuers, setissuers, deleteissuer

Comment: Thanks - the pointer to KeyVault was quite helpful. However, I'm still having difficulties, which all seem to be due to permissions. I can follow the Python docs to create and list Keys - but when I try to do anything with Certificates, I get a "403 Forbidden" error. The docs don't elaborate what permissions are needed to make these calls. Can you point me at any documentation on the permissions required to handle certificates?

Comment: @freakboy3742 Did you refer to the [document](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_azure-keyvault.html) to write your code? Could you post the details of some key code & error information? If the error information like `raise exp msrestazure.azure_exceptions.CloudError: Azure Error: AuthorizationFailed Message: The client 'XXXX' with object id 'XXXXX' does not have authorization to perform action`, please refer to https://github.com/JamborYao/ArmManagement to solve it.

Comment: As I said, I'm getting a `403 Forbidden` error. I've posted the code as an addendum to the original question.

Comment: @freakboy3742 Please refer to my update content to set access policy for certificate operations, then try your code again.

Comment: You have admonished me for not reading the documentation, but you don't appear to be reading what *I've* written. I'm *not* getting "UNAUTHORIZED". I'm getting "FORBIDDEN". I only get unauthorised if I *deliberately* use credentials that I know to be invalid.